# i have to enter the boot option and select ubuntu in UEFI everytime i boot into ubuntu

Tags: boot

i just installed ubuntu 14.04. everytime i boot my laptop(dell inspiron 5423) i have to enter the boot options and select ubuntu in UEFI options. how can i make it boot normally?

Comment: You should be able to set 14.04 as the default boot in your BIOS settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Ubuntu the default boot option on a newer laptop (UEFI)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291905/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-the-default-boot-option-on-a-newer-laptop-uefi); at the end of the accepted answer are some diagnostic instructions that you should follow in case the solutions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

All serious BIOS configurations let you set the default operating system to boot or device to boot from. Look at the manual of your computer or mainboard how to reconfigure your BIOS.