# How can I make GRUB boot by default instead of Windows Boot Manger

Tags: grub2

I'm dual-booting with Windows 10, and it sets WBM("OS Boot Manager" in the menu.) above grub. I want to have it boot grub.

HP Sleekbook Pavillion.

EDIT: UEFI on both OSes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/291905/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-the-default-boot-option-on-a-newer-laptop-uefi

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to say I use UEFI for both OSes.

Comment: I updated my comment to another answer that might be helpful.  =)

Comment: Tried running boot-repair. No dice, still boots Windows by default.

Answer (score 1):

From Ubuntu run

```
efibootmgr -v
```

to see all the entries in the boot order.
Then use efibootmgr with the -o switch to reorder them the way you want, with Ubuntu first.  See more detail in the man page:

```
man efibootmgr
```